# How to store multiple random blobs in a single file?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am generating random blobs (which in my case is a `std::string` made out of a `std::vector<unsigned char>` of arbitrary non-zero length). Blobs are random in the sense that they might be of any size within a given size range, and they contain random unsigned characters.

I am trying to write these blobs to a file(say `Blobs.txt`) in such a way that each line in my file will give me one of those generated blobs. For example, the first line of `Blobs.txt` will contain the first generated blob, the last line of `Blob.txt` will contain the last generated blob and so on.

The problem that I'm currently facing is that the blob themselves might contain newline characters(`\n`). Hence, the number of lines in my `Blobs.txt` might not be equal to the number of blobs generated.

As blobs are random, I can not make any assumptions about how each of these blobs look like.

I see that the problem is being caused by the interference of two different use cases of the newline character in a single file, one in the blob content themselves and the other as a separator in the file. And, to solve this I either have to replace the newline character with something else in my blob content and then put them in the `Blobs.txt`, or, I have to change the blob separator in my `Blobs.txt` file from newline character to something else which can not appear in my blob content(not sure if the second solution is even possible).

I know that I am going to store a fixed number of blobs in `Blobs.txt`.

I was thinking of appending some explicit fixed length numbering prior to each blob in `Blobs.txt` file, e.g., `"001:<blob 1 string>"` but this does not seem to solve the problem because `"001:"` itself might be present in some blob, and we don't know the blob sizes beforehand.

One possible solution is to write the offsets in a separate file(say `Blob_Offsets.txt`) where I store the size of each of these blobs and use these to seek `Blobs.txt`. I can't want to rely on the in-memory structures because once they are gone, I won't be able to make sense out of `Blobs.txt`.

I was wondering if it is really needed to create a separate offset file because this will increase the number of disk accesses while reading a blob?
Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you considered escaping via backslash the `\n` which are part of the blobs?

Comment: There are a *lot* of things you can do, and you've already hit on some of them, but it's hard to give any direction without a better sense of the requirements. Escaping delimiters works. Length-prefixing also works (it doesn't matter if something that looks like a length prefix occurs inside an item; you know its length before you read it). Other things work. What is *best*... depends.

Comment: As you want a txt file either convert the data to non-binary eg hex or base64.  If you you want to keep the data in binary then store it as length-prefixed so each record in the file is <4-bytes-binary-length><binary data> for forget about CR/LF as the file is binary.

Answer (score 2):

Are you committed to using one "line" per blob? I think you're going to have a tough time with that, especially if you have new-lines in your blob.

I think I would use a binary approach instead. Open the file in `binary` mode so that new-lines don't get translated to CR-LF (in Windows). Write a binary count, followed by your blob, using `stream.write`. When you read the file, use `stream.read` to read the count value, then to read that many bytes into your blob.

Comment: One line per blob is not rigid. It's one of my design choices. Actually, I wanted to use the line number in the `Blobs.txt` as a key to identify the blobs. With the approach you mentioned, I'll have to use a counter as key instead of line number.

Comment: @Romy Well, since your blob could contain anything, no matter what you try to use as a line delimiter could end up in your blob, including anything you might try to substitute for a newline in the blob. This kind of tosses the notion of lines out the widow. You write your `getblob` function, then call it for each sequential blob rather than `getline` for each sequential line. The difference then between a line number and a blob number approaches nil.

Answer (score 1):

> each line in my file will give me one of those generated blobs

and

> change the blob separator in my `Blobs.txt` file from newline character to something else

are incompatible.The things that you want to be shown on different lines in the text *editor* have to be separated by `\n` (on linux, or `\r\n` on windows, or whatever); you can't use another character, because the *editor* will not interpret it as a line break and therefore it will not show them on separate lines.

Given this, you can only change the `\n` which are *not* meant to be line separators in the first place, i.e. those that randomly happen to be in the blobs. Escaping them via `\` could be a way, e.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <range/v3/action/join.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

using namespace ranges::views;
using namespace ranges::actions;

int main()
{
    // the string that unfortunately contains \n already
    std::string s{"hello\nworld"};

    // indeed this prints 2 lines
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    // function to escape \n and \ itself
    auto constexpr escape = [](char c){
        return c == '\n' ? "\\n" :
              (c == '\\' ? "\\\\" : std::string{c});
    };

    std::string s2 = s | transform(escape) // this is a range of strings now
                       | join; // so we join all the strings together

    std::cout << s2 << std::endl; // prints 1 line
}
```

As suggested in the comments, I've escaped the `\n` control character via `\`, and since `\` is the escaping character, I have to escape it too, if I meet it in the string, which means that a `\\` (a "true" backspace in the text) must become `\\\\` (a "true" double backspace).

The escaping is easy, because you want to escape single *characters*; the un-escaping is a bit more complicated, because escaped characters are not 1 character each, but 2: the escaped character and the escaping character. So to unescape you must group the escaping and escaped characters together. E.g. the characters in the raw string (see below, the **Trivia** part) `R"(hel\\nlo\nworld)"` where you have escaped a `\` obtaining `\\` and  newline obtaining a `\n` should be grouped like in `["h","e","l",R"(\\)","n","l","o",R"(\n)","w","o","r","l","d"]`, which I think you can do via `ranges::views::group`; then you would `ranges::views::transform` by leaving strings of length 1 unaltered, and unescaping the strings of length 2 (i.e. `R"(\\)"` and `R"(\n)" would become` \`and`\n`respectively); then you would`join`.

---

**Trivia**

Instead of

```cpp
    std::string s{"hel\\nlo\nworld"};
```

you can use a raw string literal (number 6 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)) to avoid escaping characters:

```cpp
    std::string s{R"(hel\nlo
world)"};
```

where `\n` is truly just `\` followed by the letter `n`, whereas for the line break I've truly pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the middle of the string; if your editor allows you, you can put that character in the text; in Vim it comes out like this

```cpp
std::string s{R"(hel\nlo^Mworld)"};
```

where the `^M` is the single newline character, obtained via <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given some more context about how I'm going to use these blobs. These blobs are logs that I would like to replay later. 

I should be able to undo any transformation that I do on the blobs to reconstruct the original blob. So, if the original blob is `"hello<linebreak>worl\\nd"` then it will get transformed to `"hello\nworl\nd"` and I won't be able to reconstruct the original blob, right?

Comment: @romy properly done escaping is invertible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont well, if the sequence is allowed to contain an escaped `\n`, then my escaping is not proper :(

Comment: @enlico Escape backslashes themselves and escape newlines with backslashes.  Now invert by unescaping the escaped stuff.  This isn't novel?

Answer (score 0):

If file size is not an issue, you could encode your blobs in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format. 
The format doesn't use `'\n'` characters and is commonly used for representing binary data as ASCII characters on the Web.